# Loop json results

Tags: python-3.x

I'm totally new to python. I have this code:

```
import requests

won = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?status=won&start=0&api_token=xxxx'

json_data = requests.get(won).json()

deal_name = json_data ['data'][0]['title']
print(deal_name)
```

It prints the first title for me, but I would like it to loop through all titles in the json. But I can't figure out how. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you know how to loop in general or are you specifically asking how to loop over the json_data?

Comment: I have watched a lot of Youtube videoes on for loop, while loops etc. But I think it's the combination of loops and JSON which is giving me a hard time :)

Comment: When you do this: json_data = requests.get(won).json(), what you actually get is a dictionary. You should read up on those instead.

Comment: Thank you Anton vBR! I will look into dictionaries :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to read up on dictionaries and lists. It seems like your json_data["data"] contains a list, so:

Seeing you wrote this:

```
deal_name = json_data ['data'][0]['title']
print(deal_name)
```

What you are looking for is:

```
for i in range(len(json_data["data"])):
    print(json_data["data"][i]["title"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Print it with a for loop
1. `for item in json_data['data']:` will take each element in the list `json_data['data']`
2. Then we print the title property of the object using the line `print(item['title'])`

**Code:**

```
import requests
won = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?status=won&start=0&api_token=xxxx'
json_data = requests.get(won).json()
for item in json_data['data']:
    print(item['title'])
```

If you are ok with printing the titles as a list you can use **List Comprehensions**, Please refer the link in references to learn more.

```
print([x['title'] for x in json_data['data']])
```

**References:**

1. [Python Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm)
2. [Python Lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)
3. [Python Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)